# Looking for *existing* Python module for determining fiscal months

Tags: python, calendar, billing

I'm in calendar hell, and I'm hoping there exists a Python module out there that does what I want.

I'm making a Python web app that deals with subscriptions. It's conceptually similar to a cell phone plan: You start your subscription on a certain date (say `1.13.2011`), and for every billing month you have a bunch of "sessions" (phone calls), that you would be charged for.

We need to:

1. Know under which billing month each session falls.
2. Know the start time and end time of each billing month.

For example, if you signed up on `1.13.2011`, and made a phone call on `1.20.2011`, it would count on your first billing month. Same for a phone call on `2.10.2011`. But if you were to make a phone call on `2.15.2011`, it will count on your second billing month.

Regarding start and end dates: If today is `2.15.2011`, then the start date of the current month is `2.13.2011` and its end date is `3.13.2011`.

You may be thinking this is not so complicated, but then you have to consider that months have different lengths. The rule for handling this is that if your subscription started on the 30th of whatever month, its cutoff dates on each month would be `min(30, n_days_in_that_month)`. This goes for 29, 30 and 31 as well.

---

I tried coding this, but it got too complex. What I'm looking for is a ready-made, existing module that does these things.

**For the love of God don't post an answer with a sketch of an implementation!** This is useless for me. I appreciate your intentions, but in calendar hell, sketches of implementations do not help. I already have a sketch of an implementation, and debugging yours will take just as long as debugging mine.

I am only interested in using an existing module that handles such calendar tasks. **Do you know one?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Ram's edit: The `dateutil.rrule.rrule` class is the one that did *exactly* what I wanted.

Comment: _Don't post just a link as an answer_. Either post it as a comment, or explain _how_ to use the tool to solve the problem.

Comment: He asks for a module that can help, i know that is ugly, but the link is the module, he asks: 'For the love of God don't post an answer with a sketch of an implementation!'

Comment: For the record, this answer is really useful for me. Thanks diegueus9!

Comment: Please note that rrule don't solve the 29th february problem, and by extension any 30 days month if recurring date is 31th
As stated in the documentation: _Per RFC section 3.3.10, recurrence instances falling on invalid dates and times are ignored rather than coerced_

Answer (score 2):

> Regarding start and end dates: If today is 2.15.2011, then the start date of the current month is 2.13.2011 and its end date is 3.13.2011.
>
> You may be thinking this is not so complicated, but then you have to consider that months have different lengths. The rule for handling this is that if your subscription started on the 30th of whatever month, its cutoff dates on each month would be min(30, n_days_in_that_month). This goes for 29, 30 and 31 as well.

Its still pretty basic.  Use datetime module to store datetimes, so you can easily parse out the day (e.g., if `dt` is a date then `dt.day`).  A billing cycle starts on say the 29th (toughest type of case).  Let `billing_cycle_day=29`.  A billable event occurs on say the `event_day=10, event_month=5`.  Then since `event_day < billing_cycle_day` you bill to `event_month`'s bill.  Otherwise you bill to the next months bill (remembering that if month=12; you have to increment the year).

So now the billing cycle will always be from the 29th to the 28th in the next month.  The complication arises if say a date like 2/29/2011 doesn't exist.  E.g., a billing cycle start_date should be 2/29/2011 (but it doesn't exist); in this case you just make it the first on the next month.

```
billing_cycle_day = 29
year, month = 2011, 2
import datetime
def create_date_or_first_of_next_month(year, month, day):
    try:
        return datetime.date(year, month, day)
    except ValueError:
        year_n, month_n = (year, month+1) if month != 12 else (year+1, 1)
        return datetime.date(year_n, month_n, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not as hard as you think. All you have to do is write a function that given a starting day (like 13 or 30) it returns two date objects which are the beginning and end of the current fiscal month. You have already sketched out all the details in your question. Best to include an optional todayis parameter to the function so that you specify what day to use as a reference for today. For instance, if today is the 15th of October 2011, and you specify 13, the function would assume that you mean the 13th of October 2011. But if you want to rerun June data, you would specify todayis=date(2011,06,13)

The return values (start and end) allow you to pinpoint dates that belong in this fiscal month. But if the date is before the start date and less than 29 days before the start date, then you can also pinpoint in the previous fiscal month. The same goes for the next fiscal month. This is useful because there will be a lot of situations where you process data after a few days, so you will have a mix of two fiscal months to process.